# Java fails to create directory / file from the command line

Tags: java, cmd

I have an executable that generates some file, and I need to call this executable from a Java application. The command goes like this

```
Generator.exe -outputfile="path/to/file" [some other params]
```

It works fine on the command prompt, but running it from Java,all steps are executed but the file is not created.
I doubt the problem was that my java application is not able to crate files / directories, so I tried to create a directory as below

```
try {
  String envp[] = new String[1];
  envp[0] = "PATH=" + System.getProperty("java.library.path");
  Runtime.getRuntime().exec("mkdir path/to/folder", envp);
}
catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I get the following exception, even If the directory exist

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "mkdir":     
CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
```

I also tried using  `java.lang.Process` and `java.lang.Process` and I got the same exception, although the command `mkdir path/to/folder` works fine on the command prompt

Answer (score 0):

Two points:

1) You don't need to pass in the java.library.path to the mkdir command. Mkdir expects one parameter - the directory/ies you want to created.

2) Why not use the Java File class to create the directory instead? Create a File object of the path, then call the mkdirs() function on it.

Comment: 1) It does not make a difference
2) Because the file will be created by the executable, not me, and this code snippet is to mimic that behaviour